# Single Laravel endpoint in nuxt nginx setup

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nginx, single-page-application, reverse-proxy

I have a static/single-page application (nuxt/vue.js) that uses a graphql backend served by Laravel.

I am trying to serve them under a single nginx server setup where all routes (except /graphql) are served as static files (SPA).

From `/etc/nginx/conf.d/00-default.conf` I have:

```
listen 80;
root /var/www/dist;

# serve singe page application
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}

# serve /graphql endpoint from laravel
location ^~ /graphql {
  root /var/www/laravel/public;
  index index.php;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass    php-fpm:9000;
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include         fastcgi_params;
  }      
}
```

How do I setup the `root`/`alias` and `try_files` to route this query to my `laravelapp/graphql`?

---

Right now I use reverse proxy to send the request to a second nginx endpoint like so

```
location ^~ /graphql {
  proxy_redirect                      off;
  proxy_set_header Host               $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
  proxy_read_timeout 1m;
  proxy_connect_timeout 1m;
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000; # /etc/nginx/conf.d/01-laravel.conf
}
```

but I am not sure this is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a virtual host for each instance and configure each one to use a different port for example

```
server {
   listen 8081;
   server_name  www.domain.com ;
   location ^~ /graphql {
     proxy_redirect                      off;
     proxy_set_header Host               $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
     proxy_read_timeout 1m;
     proxy_connect_timeout 1m;
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000; # /etc/nginx/conf.d/01-laravel.conf
   }
}

server {
   listen 8000;
   server_name  www.domain.com ;
   location ^~ /graphql {
      root /var/www/laravel/public;
      index index.php;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

         location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass    php-fpm:9000;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include         fastcgi_params;
       }

    }
}
```

Comment: I am already using `proxy_pass` as you can see in my post. I was wondering how to do it without reverse proxy.

Comment: But I don't see that you are using different ports

Comment: check my other answer, I think this is what you are looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is creating an application load balancer with 2 target groups, each target group will point to the nginx with a different port. and each application will be mounted under different nginx port.

then create an ELB rule based on the URL, graphql URI will be forwarding traffic to the laravel point, and the default traffic will point to the other target group.

This is a neat and nice approach and does not require you to create any proxy :)

Comment: It's a great answer, but again this solution *is* a proxy. My original question is regarding how to use the `location` section of the nginx-conf in conjunction with the `root` or `alias` properties.

Comment: You can set different root and alias per location, what is the issue?

Comment: That is exactly it. How do I set the root or alias so that the /graphql-path points to Laravel's index.php and routes to /graphql so that the graphql-plugin will handle the request.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

server {

```
    listen 80;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {

        root /path/to/first-project/public;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri/index.php /index.php;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        }

    }

    # ------- second

    location /secondproject {

        root /path/to/second-project/public;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri/index.php /index.php;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I've tried as you can see in the post: `location ^~ /graphql {
  root /var/www/laravel/public;`